# How can I Identify a bot on telethon event updater

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm making a bot to forward all receiving messages on telegram.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
log_channel=-1002030404403  
async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages('me'):
        print(message.id, message.text)

       if event.is_private:
            await client.forward_messages(log_channel, event.message)
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

but this is not identifying different of bot and a user
how to filter a bots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.sender.bot` will be `True` if the `sender` is a `bot`.

You can find this in the [quick reference for `Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html#message), where it says "It bases ChatGetter and SenderGetter.", meaning `.sender` exists.